# Axios Post Request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have an API call in POSTMAN, which I am trying to replicate in nodeJS project using Axios, but the result is not the same that of a POSTMAN.

The call looks like this in POSTMAN:
[image: Postman API Call]

Inside the body element I have: models and values properties and Authorization is of type Bearer .

I get a response result as an array.

Now, I try to do the same using axios, but I get error:

### Code

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:8069/api';

axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/create/res.users', 
  data: {
    models: 'res.users',
    values: "{ 'login': 'john@gmail.com', 'name':'john', 'email':'john@gmail.com', 'password': '123123123' }"
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
  },
})
.then(function (response) {

  console.log("Register", response);
  res.status(200).send({
    message: response.data
  });

})
.catch(function (error) {

  console.log("Error", error.response.data);
  res.status(error.response.status).send({
    message: error.response.data
  });

});
```

### Error

```
{
    "message": {
        "name": "odoo.exceptions.RedirectWarning",
        "message": "You cannot create a new user from here.\n To create new user please go to configuration panel.\n74\nGo to the configuration panel",
        "arguments": [
            "You cannot create a new user from here.\n To create new user please go to configuration panel.",
            74,
            "Go to the configuration panel"
        ],
        "exception_type": "error",
        "code": 500,
        "description": "Restful API Error"
    }
}
```

Comment: ... *what* error?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have added error in the question... the error looks like its not an issue with the api call but more of a backend Odoo Server error, but this same API call is working fine in POSTMAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, This document may help you:

https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format